# @EnableEncryptableProperties is not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am new to Spring-boot and trying to encrypt password in application.properties file using jasypt library. I used @EnableEncryptableProperties with @SpringBootApplication and getting error. Don't know how to get its resolution.  Following is the dependency used in my pom.xml. I am using JDK 7 to build this Application. If you know any other framework to encrypt password in properties it will be appreciated.

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
           <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

My main class is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableJSONDoc
@EnableAsync
@EnableEncryptableProperties

public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
...
}
```

And i am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ulisesbocchio/jasyptspringboot/annotation/EnableEncryptableProperties : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:432)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3271)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:3248)
```

Answer (score 0):

The messages tells you that the class-file which should be loaded was compiled for java 8. So you need a JDK8 to use the "com.github.ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot" library.

You can have a look at spring cloud. It supports encrypted properties and only needs java 7 (afaik)

Comment: Spring cloud does not suits my requirement. To hide my password from properties file i decide to move it in Environment variable in this way: spring.datasource.password=${PASSWORD_ENV}. Problem is that properties files does not compile environment variable.